# Including <exception> header C++

Tags: c++, exception

It seems when we include `<iostream>` header, `<exception>` and `<stdexcept>` headers are included automatically.

Question is why the reference sites like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) include `<exception>` while explaining exception handling?

Is it necessary to include `<exception>` or `<stdexcept>`?

Comment: It depends on what exception you need to use, you don't need to include `<exception>` if you only need exceptions that are defined elsewhere (per the standard), e.g. `std::ios_base::failure`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always follow documentation. When documentation says that in order to use ceratain construct you need to include certain header, the header must be included. Otherwise, tomorrow `iostream` will stop including the header, and your program will fail to compile or worse - will behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 5):

You should always include what you use. The C++ standard doesn't state that any particular header **has to** include another, they are free to do so for convenience. But note that just because that happens to be the case for one compiler, it may not be the case on another (e.g. Visual Studio vs gcc)

Comment: It is usually not compiler, but library implementation dependent.

Comment: One could note that regarding macros this might not be true. For example by including one header file you should be able to rely on that no other macros (in unreserved namespace) than documented should  become defined.

Comment: Yes @SergeyA that is a more accurate statement.

Comment: [There are *some* guaranteed includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream#Includes). But not these ones, and I do understand you were deliberately simplifying.